# SQL query to copy column from one table to another table based off index value

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to formulate a query that copies the contents of one column in a table to another table and match it up with the index values.

Both tables are going to have the same index values.

Example:

Table1

```
+-----------------------------------+------------+
|               index               |    val     |
+-----------------------------------+------------+
|                 11                |     AA     |
|                 23                |     AA     |
|                 34                |     BB     |
+-----------------------------------+------------+
```

Table2

```
+-----------------------------------+
|               index               |
+-----------------------------------+
|                 34                |
|                 11                |
|                 23                |
+-----------------------------------+
```

After query is run, make table 2 reflect:

```
+-----------------------------------+------------+
|               index               |    val     |
+-----------------------------------+------------+
|                 34                |     BB     |
|                 11                |     AA     |
|                 23                |     AA     |
+-----------------------------------+------------+
```

I would appreciate any help offered. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite understand why you would like to do this, but it could look something like:

```
Alter table BTABLE add val varchar(10);
update BTABLE  bta set val = (select ata.val from ATABLE ata where ata.index = bta.index);
```

the only thing is, this way you would have 2 completely identical tables...

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do what you describe, is to drop `Table2` and recreate it as a copy of `Table1`:

```
DROP TABLE Table2;

CREATE TABLE Table2 AS
SELECT * FROM Table1;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=57b93169d2c7d7835f39cb31a7937757).
Results (for `Table2`):

```
> index | val
> ----: | :--
>    11 | AA 
>    23 | AA 
>    34 | BB
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Irina Avram told you, Why do you want to copy a column that already exists in your database.
You can use JOIN and a SELECT statement to get what you want, without adding more datas in your database.

```
SELECT Table2.index, Table1.val FROM Table2 JOIN Table1 ON Table2.index = Table1.index
```

[Learn more about JOIN](https://sql.sh/cours/jointures)